# PHPUnit slow on windows 10

Tags: windows, phpunit

I'm experiencing that PHPUnit is really slow on Win 10 compared to Win 7. Did anyone experience the same?

(I'm using release PHPUnit 4.8 with Xampp)

Comment: Windows 10 OS can be slow depending on how it's configured. Check out [this site](http://fossbytes.com/how-to-fix-slow-performance-issue-in-windows-10-and-increase-overall-system-speed/) on tips to increase speed. Hope this helps - at least on the OS side.

Comment: Followed the instructions in the site (tried with custom memory 5000 MB and 20000 MB), but had no increased performance. What I did experience, is that when I closed all other windows, PHPUnit was running 3x faster, but still slower than before.

Comment: After some investigation I found that this was caused by other processes running. Once these processes closed, the performance was acceptable.